# mvc3 to mvc4 problems

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have just turned my mvc3 project into a mvc4 project. I made a new project, did not modify any config files, moved my controllers, views and models. I then imported mysql to the project.

Everything works fine but I got a problem with the whole authorization process.

If I add that in my view:

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Something
        }
        else
        {
             // Another Thing
        }
```

It will always trigger something. It will think that I am authenticated even if I am not (I have checked my cookies and I have none).

And of course I can reach all of my controllers which should be protected with `[Authorize]`.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem.

The problem comes from the fact that I created an empty project. It seems that no configuration at all has been made.

You have to make a default project in order to have the correct setup.